# Mouse speed - reduce when moving slowly

Tags: mouse, mouse-pointer

When I'm moving the mouse to grab a corner of a window to resize it I often overshoot several times as it's hard to move exactly those last few pixels.

Is there a way with Ubuntu to reduce the cursor / mouse movement ratio when moving the mouse slowly?

I guess what I'm looking for is something like "Enhance Pointer Precision" in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

are you using kde? if so, launch system settings then select "input devices" in the "hardware" section.  in the left column, select "mouse" then select the "advanced" tab.

there is a setting for acceleration - my own is set for 2x and works quite well.

Comment: I'm using the default desktop with Ubuntu 18. I'm not after acceleration. I'm after Enhance Pointer Precision - e.g. see this Mouse Ballistics article (https://blog.codinghorror.com/mouse-ballistics/ ).